# Maximum distance between local lows. Python

Tags: python, sequence

The file contains a sequence of numbers of unknown length (possibly empty). It is necessary to determine the required sequence character in one view of the file and without memorizing the sequence in the array.

The local minimum of a sequence {ai}i=1,...,N is a subsequence {aj}j=k,...,l of a given sequence, the elements of which are equal to each other and for which the ratios are performed: 1)k = 1 or ak−1 > ak; 2)l = N or al+1 > al

How to find Maximum distance between local lows? (Python)

Comment: please add an example file, with maximum distance

Comment: 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0

Answer must be 3